# Serial Communication with HV5623

Tags: shift-register, open-drain

I'm just trying to understand the communication protocol with the HV5623. Here is the Function table:

[image: HV5623 function Table]

I want to be able to hold the HV output while I shift in the new states into the shift register, then enable the HV output then rinse and repeat. My understanding is that I should send the data with LE Low, BL high, and POL high and then pulse LE in order to set the shift register values to the HV output.

For sending data am I able to use I2C where Data->SDA and CLK->SCL? Does I2C continuously pulse the clock or does it only pulse the clock when there is a bit to send? My understanding is that if the clock only pulses when data is being sent then after the data is shifted in, then this set up will work, but if the clock is always running, then the LE pulled high will have to be timed fairly precisely.

Any confirmation (or explanation of why I'm wrong) that using I2C with a switching LE and BL/POL held high would be appreciated

Comment: No, that's not I2C. Not compatible. That's simply a serial shift register.

Comment: There's extra clock edges during an I2C transmission in addition to the data bits (the start and stop bits), so you'd have no way to control the data for those "bits". You'd probably have to write your own driver as well since most I2C drivers check for the "ack/nack" bit for proper communication. @Justme is correct: use a SPI peripheral or bit bang a GPIO pin.

Comment: @SittinHawk actually there are no extra clocks due to start and stop, as they are not bits, but conditions where data changes while clock is high. But the first falling edge would happen after start condition where data is low. This can be ignored by the chip. But there are 9 low-going clock pulses per 8 data bits due to ACK bit, and the chip would thus load in an extra bit. And the I2C master would most likely not continue after NACK condition. All in all, still impossible. Or at least not the way it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An I2C host would fail to communicate as it would not see that chip as a valid I2C device, because it is not an I2C device so it won't talk I2C protocol.

The interface is a simple serial shift register. It can be communicated with SPI peripheral or simply by toggling GPIO pins in software. You can leave BL and POL high.